# How can you set breakpoints in IDEA that are recognized by Chrome while using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint in javascript while using Intellij IDEA, but have it recognized by chrome's devtools. We are using gulp for our development web server. Is there a way to make it so that chrome recognizes the breakpoint I set in my IDE? Presuming yes please provide all of the steps required to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you type `debugger;` in your code chrome should stop at that point.